# UITableViewで表示ができない。

Tags: swift

現在の状況

APIを通じてUITableViewで画像を表示しようとしたのですが、表示されません。

解決策を現在探していますので、何か助言を頂ければと考え投稿しました。

解決策1

```
cell.artworkUrl.text = result["artworkUrl100"]と記述する、が画像は表示されず。。
```

解決策2

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath)と記述 failed
```

SetImageWithURLでartworkUrlにあるAPIの情報をセットしたのちに、その情報を表示するコードが存在していなかったため追加した。

```
//tavleviewに対して引数内を継承している
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath        indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

//dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifierはcellに参照(使い回しが出来るよう)にする
//as! ListCellは、ListCellがNilだとエラーが出るようにする  
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListCell

//定数resultsにcellが代入されたら、画像を表示する。   
if let result = results?[indexPath.row] {
    if let artworkUrl = result["artworkUrl100"] as? String {
        cell.artworkImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: artworkUrl)!)
    } else {
        cell.artworkImageView.image = nil
    }

// 曲のtrackNameとartistNameを表示する

    cell.trackLabel.text = result["trackName"] as? String
    cell.artistLabel.text = result["artistName"] as? String
}
// cellの内容を戻り値として返す。    
return cell
}
```

Comment: ネットワーク上の画像データをロードしているのだとしたら、ダウンロードできずに、タイムアウトしているということも、考えられるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: APIを用いてデータを取ってきて、そのデータを出力するのでありえるかもしれません。
ありがとうございます。